# How change Edittext cursor and bubble under cursor dynamically

Tags: android

[I wanted to change bubble under cursor which is same as background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSEzt.png)

Answer (score 0):

you have to set cursor drawable run time try this:

```
             try {
                 Field field = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
                 field.setAccessible(true);
                 field.set(yourEditText, R.drawable.your_cursor_drawable);
             } catch (Exception ignored) {
             }
```